# How to prevent bash from running when variable is undefined

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash       
$myval=/home
ls $mval <- unexpected misspelling
```

Is there a way to stop the ls command from executing since `$mval` is not defined?

**NOTE** that this can not be checked for existence because it was a typo. I am looking more for a property that can be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `set -u` option which aborts if you try to expand an unset variable.  However note that `$myval=/home` is not valid syntax and wont set a variable.  You need to drop the `$`.

```
#!/bin/bash 

set -u
     
myval=/home
ls "$mval"
```

> -u
>
> > Treat unset variables and parameters other than the special parameters ‘@’ or ‘*’ as an error when performing parameter expansion. An error message will be written to the standard error, and a non-interactive shell will exit.

Comment: Much better than last comment that said check for existence. Much appreciated!